# Does "abstellen" and "setzen" have same common?

Tags: difference

*Abstellen* means turn off or switch off while *setzen* is to lay or put something. But does this two verbs have same common?

i.e.

> Sie können Ihr Fahrrad im Keller abstellen.

and

> Die Assistentin setzt den Hund auf das Sofa.

Comment: _"Abstellen means turn off or switch off"_ not in the context of _"Sie können Ihr Fahrrad im Keller abstellen."_  The latter means _You can put your bicycle in the basement._

Comment: Please do a proper dictionary lookup of the words before asking.

Comment: What do you mean by *have same common*?

Answer (score 2):

"etwas abstellen" can either mean to turn something off or put something in someplace where it can 'stand'. "stellen/aufstellen/abstellen" is related to "stehen" which translate to "to stand". So what's the thing about abstellen?
Ich *stelle* mein Fahrrad ab -> correct, as it stands in someplace after you do it
Ich *stelle* die Kisten dort ab -> correct, as they can stand
Ich *stelle* das Blatt Papier hier ab -> **incorrect**, a sheet of papier *lays* somewhere and does not stand. The correct use would be:
Ich *lege* das Blatt Papier hier ab -> *ablegen/legen* means something *lays*
"*absetzen*" is from "*setzen*" -> 'to *sit*'. If something can sit, you can use "absetzen".

So now again in short:
If the Object can **sit**, you can use "ab**setzen**"
If the Object can **stand**, you can use "ab**stellen**"
If the Object can **lay**, you can use "ab**legen**"

Comment: Quite good answer, just one small addition: if it is a person you drop of somewhere after giving him/her a lift, you always use "absetzen", even though a person can also stand or lay

Comment: Yes, good addition. I'm sure there are a few more exceptions to this rule, but in most cases it applies.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Indeed, in that example *abstellen* would suggest the person is like a mannequin or dummy and *ablegen* sounds as if you want to dispose of a dead body.